# pushRoute from Java on new intent not working

Tags: java, flutter, dart

I am trying to open a page in flutter from the onNewIntent function in Java. However, it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Java

```
    @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        String paymentId = uri.getQueryParameter("id");
        intent.putExtra("paymentId", paymentId);

        FlutterEngine flutterEngine = new FlutterEngine(this);
        flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().executeDartEntrypoint(
                DartEntrypoint.createDefault()
        );

        flutterEngine.getNavigationChannel().pushRoute("process");
    }
}
```

Flutter

```
Future<void> main(List<String> args) async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    initialRoute: "/",
    routes: {
      '/': (context) => Init(),
      '/process': (context) => StartProcess(),
    },
  ));
}
```

What i am trying to do is open a browser to make a payment. When the browser closes, I return to the onNewIntent function. From there I want flutter to open the process page. Maybe there is another way to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved my goal by working with MethodChannel: [platform channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)